# DPDK Ports Stuck in uio_pci_generic

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, pci, dpdk

My Linux server holding DPDK application got rebooted, once it came up. All the ports which were bonded to UIO_IGB got into a weird state. They are bounded to uio_pci_generic after reboot and unable to unbind those. Even with force.

I had to hard reset or complete power cycle to get those back normal.

Is there any way to handle this issue?

```
python dpdk-devbind.py  --status

Other Network devices
=====================
0000:05:00.0 'Device 15ab' unused=uio_pci_generic
0000:05:00.1 'Device 15ab' unused=uio_pci_generic


# python dpdk-devbind.py  -u 0000:05:00.0
0000:05:00.0 Device  is not currently managed by any driver

# python dpdk-devbind.py --force  -u 0000:05:00.0
0000:05:00.0 Device  is not currently managed by any driver
```

Comment: From the logs it is clear device is not bound to `ixge` or `uio_pci_generic`. Can you explain `why are you trying to unbind them again`? why not try to bind with kernel driver for unbinded device `Other Network Device`?

Comment: @VipinVarghese, DPDK is the mechanism to utilize network bandwidth in user space. What you are talking about?

Comment: I think it's default state and means that nobody is using it with specific (UIO_IGB) module. Can you try to simply bind it?

Comment: @andriy logs shared from Kaushik, shows after reboot there is no driver attached to PCIe device. We can ask @kaushik to confirm using `lspci -ks B:D:F`. Hence in my comments, I have asked `why are trying unbind, when there no driver bonded to it?`. If  one needs to use DPDK you have to bind with compatible driver.

Comment: I have tried to bind it back to ixgbe, It threw error saying cannot bind to ixgbe driver.

On debugging I found the EEPROM on these are corrupted after using DPDK and rebooting the system,. Whereas I am able to bind to IGB_UIO. 

How can I reset the eeprom to assign it back to IXGBE

Comment: Please do share the logs and debug steps too. Showcasing the EEPROM corruption will be helpful too.It will better to get in touch with the NIC driver team.

Comment: Assuming there is a possibility, the kernel is updated to a newer version after reboot. But not the firmware package. If it is ubuntu OS can you run `update-initramfs -u` and reboot. Or download latest ixgbe driver `make; make install; update-initramfs -u` then reboot.

Comment: @KaushikKoneru are there any updates on this? if yes, please share

Comment: '''update-initramfs -u''' resolved my issue.Thank you @vi

Answer (score 0):

@kaushik from the logs the device is not bound to any driver `ixgbe` or `uio_pci_generic`. You are better off either bind it back to kernel `ixgbe` driver or `igb_uio, vfio-pci or uio_pci_generic`.

Note: I have tried to explain this in the comments.

EDIT-1: based on the comments, the issue is resolved by recompiling igb_uio and forcing the firmware to be update for the driver `make; make install; update-initramfs -u`

Comment: are there any updates from your end, as discussed in the answers the ports are bound to no driver,